# Socket.io and express ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I am getting the error :ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Send button doesn't work. There is also no welcome message displayed at the start for the newly joined user. I tried to solve it by changing ports to localhost. I've seen similar threads in this forum. No solutions help. What are the possible solutions to this problem? Is it related to false endpoint address?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlM7s.png)

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import queryString from 'query-string';
import io from "socket.io-client";

import Messages from '../Messages/Messages';
import InfoBar from '../InfoBar/InfoBar';
import Input from '../Input/Input';

import './Chat.css';

let socket;

const Chat = ({ location }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [room, setRoom] = useState('');
  const [users, setUsers] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000';

  useEffect(() => {
    const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search);

    socket = io(ENDPOINT);

    setRoom(room);
    setName(name)

    socket.emit('join', { name, room }, (error) => {
      if(error) {
        alert(error);
      }
    });
  }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on('message', message => {
      setMessages(messages => [ ...messages, message ]);
    });
    
    socket.on("roomData", ({ users }) => {
      setUsers(users);
    });
}, []);

  const sendMessage = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if(message) {
      socket.emit('sendMessage', message, () => setMessage(''));
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="outerContainer">
      <div className="container">
          <InfoBar room={room} />
          <Messages messages={messages} name={name} />
          <Input message={message} setMessage={setMessage} sendMessage={sendMessage} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Chat;
```

Server part

```js
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const socketio = require('socket.io');
const cors = require('cors');

const { addUser, removeUser, getUser, getUsersInRoom } = require('./users');

const router = require('./router');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketio(server);

app.use(cors());
app.use(router);

io.on('connect', (socket) => {
  socket.on('join', ({ name, room }, callback) => {
    const { error, user } = addUser({ id: socket.id, name, room });

    if(error) return callback(error);

    socket.join(user.room);

    socket.emit('message', { user: 'admin', text: `${user.name}, welcome to room ${user.room}.`});
    socket.broadcast.to(user.room).emit('message', { user: 'admin', text: `${user.name} has joined!` });

    io.to(user.room).emit('roomData', { room: user.room, users: getUsersInRoom(user.room) });

    callback();
  });

  socket.on('sendMessage', (message, callback) => {
    const user = getUser(socket.id);

    io.to(user.room).emit('message', { user: user.name, text: message });

    callback();
  });

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    const user = removeUser(socket.id);

    if(user) {
      io.to(user.room).emit('message', { user: 'Admin', text: `${user.name} has left.` });
      io.to(user.room).emit('roomData', { room: user.room, users: getUsersInRoom(user.room)});
    }
  })
});

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => console.log(`Server has started.`));
```

Comment: can you add the server part? you also might as well change to `const ENDPOINT = ':5000';`

Comment: Yes, looks like an issue with the server part, all this is fine

Comment: Post was updated. Server part above.

Comment: Updated with backend code!